# Update a UI thread whille another ui thread is loading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm trying to create a secondary windows (GUI_2) from the first one (GUI_1) and update a label from GUI_2 while GUI_1 is initializing. (Like a loading screen).

I tried with Task.Factory, Dispatcher but I think that something is missing to me.

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
        DispatcherOperation op = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
           Window1 gui = new Window1();
           gui.Show();
        }));
     });
 }
```

With this, my GUI_2 is open but if I tried to update the label, it just show the last value. (ie: a for i = 0 to 10 with thread.sleep show just the 10 value).

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT :**
I have tried this code :

```
public partial class Loading : Window
{
    public static object uiContext;
    private List<string> paths;
    private List<Color>  colors;
    public Loading(List<string> _paths, List<Color> _colors)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        paths = _paths;
        colors = _colors;
    }
    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard s = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("sb");
        s.Begin();  // Start animation
        await Task.Run(() => EXCEL.Analogize(paths, this, colors));
        Close();
    }
    public void UpdateWindow(string text, int percent)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            progress_label.Content = text;
            progress.Value = percent;
        });
    }
}
```

and in my EXCEL.Analogize I use gui_loading.UpdateWindow(text,percent);

It's working but if i tried to do the same with a windows class, it doesn't update anymore.

Comment: Consider using only one window, you can show the loading screen as a child of the mainwindow's root grid.

Comment: What is the code that you have tried and is not working?

Comment: I tried the one post in the first topic or to put dispatcher.invoke in a methode of the second GUI

Comment: Why do I get downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe is in GUI_2 UI task busy with load, and only show when it complete. Try to put update on other task and sync it with UI.

In GUI_2 ctor

**EDIT:**

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _SyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            UpdateLabel();
        }
        SynchronizationContext _SyncContext = null;
        private async void UpdateLabel()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
                {
                    Load(i);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            });

        }

        private void Load(int i)
        {
            SendOrPostCallback updateUI = new SendOrPostCallback(arg =>
            {
                yourLabelName.Content = $"{i}/10";
            });

            _SyncContext.Send(updateUI, null);
        }
    }
```

and im calling that window like this from mainWindow constructor:

```
 Window1 gui = new Window1();
            gui.Show();
```

This one i tested and it's working for me.

**EDIT 2**
Yes it is possible
One way is to pass parameter directly in constructor 
like `Window1(string text);` and when you call that window you pass parameter `Window1(text);`
Second way is ( and i prefer this) to make Interface(something like IWindow) and put simple Load method in it
like this

```
public interface IWindow
    {
       void Load(string text);
    }

public partial class Window1 : Window , IWindow
    {
//here you implement Load(string text) method.
```

then you pass that IWindow im MainWindow constructor with some DI resolve it(Autofac, Unity)[Autofac](https://autofac.org/)
and from mainWindow you can instantiate something like this:

//MainWindow constructor

```
MainWindow(IWindow iWindow)
{
_iWindow = iWindow;
}
public IWindow _iWindow { get; private set; }
```

and have Load() method in MainWindow

```
public void Load()
        {
            _iWindow.Load(textToPassAsParameter);
//this will call Load method from Window1
        }
```

To call that load method you can do it in xaml
**ADD** namespaces

```
 xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions">
```

and call Load method from MainWindo(that will call Load from Window1)

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="Load"
                                 TargetObject="{Binding}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Check for dependency injection becouse you pass interface as parameter and it need to return class that uses that interface( Window1).

And I highly recommend to use MVVM and ViewModels for ea View, and not to do code behind.

**Edit 3**
I think you can acomplish what you want with xceed toolkit(NuGet package), and bind BusyContent with some property that is changing(to show load progress)

in xaml of your MainWindow surround your area that is loading with

namespace

```
xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

surround with

```
<extToolkit:BusyIndicator Grid.Row="1"
                                  BusyContent="Loading..."
                                  IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">

<!-- your loading area -->
```

and IsBusy is property in MainWindow

```
private bool _isBusy;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return _isBusy; }
            set
            {
                if (_isBusy != value)
                {
                    _isBusy = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

that get's updated in you Load method

```
private void Load()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            // some load logic
            //{
            // IsBusy=false;
            //}
        }
```

and you call that load method in MainWindow constructor. This way you don't need Window1, as this toolkit will be placed as child inside your mainWindow and will work as progress bar.
 where if you write in `BusyContent="This is xceed progress bar..."` you will get child loadWindow from xceed like this.[image]

Comment: I tried but the windows finish to load only after the count is over.

Comment: sry, haven't tested it. Now i tested and it was like you said, so i make some changes and it works just fine in this case. window1.xaml is just label to show purpose. like this <Label x:Name="yourLabelName" Width="100" Height="30" FontSize="15" />

Comment: And i've made Thread.Sleep(1000) becouse it run up to 10 so fast, this is just so it shows how it count up.

Comment: It's almost what I would love ! the counter is inside the windows1, is it possible to update from the first windows with something like gui.UpdateLabel("text"); ?

Comment: I have update 2 ways how could it be possible to pass parameter. Im not sure is it clear enough, but it's not easy topic to explain in simple code. I did my besto to make it clear.

Comment: that's clear, but I think it's me whi didn't explain well what I would like. I would like to open the second windows, and while the first windows is loading data(taking a long time), the update are send to the second windows to display them like "Opening : Loading file 1/5..." then "Opening : Loading file 2/5..." etc.

Comment: That's it, i'll try to work with that ! Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: Glad i could help :) it's a long answer but covers different aproaches .